# How to properly exit MPI application after error in a single process

Tags: c++, error-handling, mpi

I am building a C++ library based on MPI. I would like to know how to properly terminate the application (viz. all processes) following an error in a single process. Say we have a function like:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    {do stuff here...}
    if (error)
    {
        {MPI_Calls?}
    }
}
```

As it is, this function will be called by all processes at approximately the same time, but the `if`-branch will typically be called a single process. What MPI calls should be made in order to communicate to the other processes that there was an error in one of the processes and that the application should be terminated? Could this be encapsulated in a standalone `Error` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`MPI_Abort`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Abort.html) for that. It tells all processes to stop running; it is the equivalent to the `exit` command in C for MPI.